# Caracteres especiales en Resources C#

Tags: c#

¿Como puedo poner de nombre de una cadena un carácter especial como = + && || etc...?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando pongo de nombre un carácter especial como "=" me marca un error

Answer (score 0):

Al compilar se genera una clase estática a partir del archivo de recursos, creando una propiedad con el nombre de cada clave.

Esto nos permite acceder a los recursos a través de estas propiedades de sólo lectura:

```
MiProyecto.Properties.Resources.Clave_del_Recurso
```

Por este motivo lo lógico sería que las claves de los recursos tuvieran las mismas restricciones que los nombres de propiedades:

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#identifiers

Sin embargo al compilar el archivo de recursos se reemplazan algunos de los caracteres no válidos en identificadores por el carácter de subrayado.
Igualmente, añade un carácter de subrayado al inicio del identificador si éste no empieza por letra o subrayado.

No he encontrado documentación sobre los caracteres válidos en los nombres de recursos pero se pueden encontrar en el código de msbuild:

```
// When fixing up identifiers, we will replace all these chars with
// a single char that is valid in identifiers, such as '_'.
private static readonly char[] s_charsToReplace = new char[] { ' ',
'\u00A0' /* non-breaking space */, '.', ',', ';', '|', '~', '@',
'#', '%', '^', '&', '*', '+', '-', '/', '\\', '<', '>', '?', '[',
']', '(', ')', '{', '}', '\"', '\'', ':', '!' };
private const char ReplacementChar = '_';
```

https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/master/src/Tasks/system.design/stronglytypedresourcebuilder.cs

Por lo tanto, los caracteres admitidos en los nombres de los recursos son los mismos que en el nombre de identificadores de c# más los que se encuentran en esta lista.

Como puedes ver el carácter '=' no cumple ninguna de las dos condiciones.